# How to display server name and ping result only from powershell script in html web page

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create the script for checking if the servers are online, which will be displayed as HTML web page using "ConvertTo-Html" property. I also applied some small CSS into it.

Here is my code:

```
$Header = @"
<style>
table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
</style>
"@


$OS = Test-Connection -ComputerName Server1, Server2, Server3 | ConvertTo-Html
ConvertTo-Html -Body "$OS" -Title "Fragment" -Head $Header | Out-File StatusReport.html
```

Output result in the file "[StatusReport.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHscn.png)" shows too much unnecessary information (photo attached). How can I display only few of them: Server name, ping result?

Comment: before you convert to html ... use `Select-Object` to grab ONLY the properties you  want.

Answer (score 2):

Ass Lee commented, you'll need to select the properties you want from the output. There are quite a few properties but none of them are `Server` or `result`.

To see a list of the properties, pipe the output to `Get-Member`

```
Test-Connection google.com -count 1 | Get-Member
```

You can also use `Format-List *` to see the properties and values

```
Test-Connection google.com -count 1 | Format-List *
```

Once you know the properties you're after you can select them by name

```
Test-Connection google.com -count 1 | Select-Object Address,IPv4Address,StatusCode
```

If you want to rename the properties, you can use [calculated properties](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx)

```
Test-Connection google.com -count 1 |
    Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$_.Address}},IPv4Address,@{n='Result';e={'Successful'}}
```

However this does not account for any failed ping results. Here's a bit of code that will gather the successes and failures, then combine the two. Note that the property names need to match.

```
$targets = 'server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'dontexist'

$success = Test-Connection -ComputerName $targets -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errors |
               Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$_.address}},IPv4Address,@{n='Result';e={'Successful'}}

$failed = $errors.exception.message |
              Where-Object {$_ -match "computer '(.+?)'"} |
                  Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$matches.1}},
                                @{n='IPv4Address';e={"N/A"}},
                                @{n='Result';e={'Failed'}}

$success + $failed
```

You can use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1) to make the code easier to read and maintain.

```
$params = @{
    ComputerName  = 'server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'dontexist'
    Count         =  1
    ErrorAction   = 'SilentlyContinue'
    ErrorVariable = 'errors'
}

$success = Test-Connection @params |
               Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$_.address}},
                             IPv4Address,
                             @{n='Result';e={'Successful'}}

$failed = $errors.exception.message |
              Where-Object {$_ -match "computer '(.+?)'"} |
                  Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$matches.1}},
                                @{n='IPv4Address';e={"N/A"}},
                                @{n='Result';e={'Failed'}}

$success + $failed
```

Combining this with a slightly modified version of your code we end up with this as the final script.

```
$Header = @"
<style>
table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
</style>
"@

$params = @{
    ComputerName  = 'server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'dontexist'
    Count         =  1
    ErrorAction   = 'SilentlyContinue'
    ErrorVariable = 'errors'
}

$success = Test-Connection @params |
               Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$_.address}},
                             IPv4Address,
                             @{n='Result';e={'Successful'}}

$failed = $errors.exception.message |
              Where-Object {$_ -match "computer '(.+?)'"} |
                  Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$matches.1}},
                                @{n='IPv4Address';e={"N/A"}},
                                @{n='Result';e={'Failed'}}

$success + $failed |
    ConvertTo-Html -Title "Fragment" -Head $Header |
        Set-Content -Path StatusReport.html -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Thank you, Doug, you helped me a lot