# How to set a variable for test-connection to pull the ipv4address?

Tags: powershell

I apologize for the terrible title, i had no clue how to word this.

I want to setup a script that when ran, it does a if-then command that outputs the computer name, if it failed or succeeded to connect, and what the IP is if connected.

So far what I have is:

```
    $computer1 = 'google.com'
    $computer2 = 'netflix.com'
if (Test-Connection "$computer1" -count 1 -Quiet) {"$computer1 connected"} else {"$computer1 failed"}
if (Test-Connection "$computer2" -Count 1 -Quiet) {"$computer2 connected"} else {"$computer2 failed"}
```

So that outputs:

> Google.com connected
>
> Netflix.com failed

How can I take it a step further so that when it returns it says something like:

> Google.com connected "IPv4address"

where it shows the IPv4 address as well as connected and the computername?

almost like how when you originally do test-connection:

```
test-connection google.com
```

and that returns:

```
Source        Destination     IPV4Address

------        -----------     -----------    
DOMINATOR     google.com      172.217.9.206
DOMINATOR     google.com      172.217.9.206
DOMINATOR     google.com      172.217.9.206
DOMINATOR     google.com      172.217.9.206
```

Reason im asking is because when a connection fails, it throws an annoying:

```
PS C:\Users\Andrew> Test-Connection netflix.com, google.com
Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'netflix.com' failed: Error due to lack of resources
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Connection netflix.com, google.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (netflix.com:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand

Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'netflix.com' failed: Error due to lack of resources
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Connection netflix.com, google.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (netflix.com:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand

Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'netflix.com' failed: Error due to lack of resources
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Connection netflix.com, google.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (netflix.com:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand

Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'netflix.com' failed: Error due to lack of resources
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Connection netflix.com, google.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (netflix.com:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand


Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms)
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    --------
DOMINATOR     google.com      172.217.13.78                                             32       14
DOMINATOR     google.com      172.217.13.78                                             32       14
DOMINATOR     google.com      172.217.13.78                                             32       15
DOMINATOR     google.com      172.217.13.78                                             32       17
```

and sure you can add "-quiet"

but then it just says:

```
False
True
```

Any help would be great cause im stumped

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64829915/4085331)

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to handle failures gracefully.

```
$targets = 'server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'dontexist'

$success = Test-Connection -ComputerName $targets -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable errors |
               Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$_.address}},IPv4Address,@{n='Result';e={'Successful'}}

$failed = $errors.exception.message |
              Where-Object {$_ -match "computer '(.+?)'"} |
                  Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$matches.1}},
                                @{n='IPv4Address';e={"N/A"}},
                                @{n='Result';e={'Failed'}}

$success + $failed
```